# Magento 2: Push product id to cookie

Tags: magento2, cookie

I have a product list like this:
[image: https://prnt.sc/rk1svv]

my checkbox value is product id, how to click button `request more info` and add product id in checkbox to cookie.

Any help? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the cookie in js file using below method,

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'mage/cookies'
    ], function ($) {
       $.cookie('cookie_name', 'value', { path: '/' });//Set the cookies
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain further so that it can work in my case, Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelHa About Magento cookies? OR how to use it in your case?

Comment: @Roshan How to use it in my case? please explain.

Comment: Refer this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432221/store-multiple-checkbox-state-with-jquery-cookie-js/10434496